# JUnit тест метода с консольным вводом

Tags: java, консоль, юнит-тесты, junit

Есть класс InfoInput в котором есть метод с консольным вводом

```
public static Person determiningGroup()
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        System.out.println("Enter age");
        Integer age = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());

        if(age>=schoolAge && age<=studentAge){
            return new Schoolkid(age);
        }
        else if(age>=studentAge && age<=adultAge){
            return new Student(age);
        }
        else if(age>=adultAge && age<=pensionerAge){
            return new Adult(age);
        }
        else if(age>=pensionerAge && age<maxAge){
            return new Pensioner(age);
        }
        else return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Написал простенький тест к нему:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    Person person = InfoInput.determiningGroup();
    Assert.assertNotNull(person);
}
```

Проблема в том, что тест доходит до ввода и висит, так как ничего в консоль ввести нельзя. В этом собственно и вопрос: как вводить в консоль во время теста?

Comment: Используйте логгер или инкапсулируйте Ваш консольный вывод и замочте его в тесте, еще есть powermock, при помощи него можно мочить статику.

Comment: Сделайте InputStream аргументом и передавайте его, после чего в тесте передавайте произвольную реализацию InputStream. Внутренний класс системы не должен заниматься прямым чтением ввода.